# Using logits output of BertForSequenceClassification in BCEWithLogitsLoss function

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am fine-tuning BertForSequenceClassification, where the class labels are 0 or 1. Due to the data imbalance, I want to use weights as recommended in [this link](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/class-weights-for-bertforsequenceclassification/1674/6).

The code structure is as follows:

```
config = BertConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased', num_labels=2)
model = BertForSequenceClassification(config)

loss_function = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=pos_weight)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for input_ids, attention_mask, targets in train_dataloader:
        outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        loss = loss_function(outputs.logits, targets)
        ...
```

In this line of code:

```
loss = loss_function(outputs.logits, targets)
```

I encounter the following error:

```
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([64])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([64, 2]))
```

However, the dimensions seems reasonable to me because:

- The dimension of outputs.logits is 64x2 (batch size = 64, num_labels = 2).
- The target has a dimension of 64 (batch size = 64, label can be either 0 or 1).

What am I missing? How can I incorporate the logit output of BertForSequenceClassification into the BCEWithLogitsLoss loss function?